# no dev/video0 Ubuntu 22.04.3 mac-2015

Tags: 22.04, macbook, camera

i cannot capture no photo/video

```
errors thrown by cheese:

(cheese:30514): cheese-CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:30514): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:30514): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:30514): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:30514): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:30514): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:30514): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:30514): CRITICAL **: 22:47:19.015: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed

(cheese:30514): Clutter-CRITICAL **: 22:47:22.758: Unable to create dummy onscreen: No foreign surface, and wl_shell unsupported by the compositor
```

cannot find dev/video0

```
 ~ % v4l2-ctl --list-devices   
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

```
/ % dev/video*
zsh: no matches found: dev/video*
```

os:  Ubuntu 22.04.3
model: 2015 Macbook

Comment: Can you be more specific about your macbook model?

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.